# Google Apps Script: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler works as WebApp but not in sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created an HTML file that displays data that has been sourced from a Google spreadsheet. The google apps script code.gs file is a container bound script.

The *Code.gs* file has two functions that use *HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile()* to run/execute/evaluate a HTML file.

**doGet(e)** runs as a *webApp*.

**onOpen()** runs as a *simple Trigger*.

Both functions are using the same html file ("index.html"). The bottom of the "index.html" is shown below.

**index.html**
in the `<script></script>` tag at the bottom there is an EventListener.
The event listener does seem to work.

**`window.addEventListener('load', populateList);`** runs **`populateList()`**.

**`populateList()`** basically runs *`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()`* twice.

I know the event listener works because if you comment out 1 of the 2 *google.script.run.withSuccessHandler* lines, **Apps Script > Executions** only shows one error.

Both google scripts functions, **getUser()** and **valuesForList()** do return values.

so the questions is:
Why does the **getUser()** and **valuesForList()** functions work when the html file runs as a webApp, but not when run in a sidebar?

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  //var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('My custom sidebar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

**index.html (relevant portions of)**

```
    <script>
      /* Commands to run Functions are added at the bottom of this index.html file so that the
      page can finish rendering before trying to execute anything else. */
      
      /* This command allows you to specify a client-side callback function to run when the server 
      responds. If the server function returns a value, the API passes the value to the new 
      function as a parameter.
      */
      function populateList(){
        /*
        In this example 'getUser' runs (Apps Script Function), then passes the value back to
        'onUserSuccess' which can be found at the top of this page.
        */
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onUserSuccess).getUser();
        
        /*
        In the second example 'valuesForList' runs (Apps Script Function), then passes the value back
        to 'onListSuccess' which can be found at the top of this page.
        */
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onListSuccess).valuesForList('suppliersList');
      }
      
      /* Use the 'load' event to execute the above 'populateList' Function. This listener waits
      for the webpage to fully load before initiating any other functions. */
      window.addEventListener('load', populateList);
      </script>
    
    </html>
```

**getUser.gs**

```
as long as they are logged into their Google account.
*/

function getUser() {
  
  // get user email address
  var theUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  // return this value to parent function
  return theUser;
  
}
```

Comment: Is there a message logged in the executions page?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information of `but not when run in a sidebar`?

Comment: @Tanaike - I have put the contents of getUser() in the post. valuesForList() returns a 2D array. The array is generated from a "range" of the active sheet.  Is there any other information you need?

Comment: @Rubén -  executions page shows: 
| Head | valuesForList | Unknown | Sep 19, 2021, 7:42:18 PM | 0 s | Failed |

Comment: @dfear Please expand that row in the executions page to check if there is an error message.

Comment: Can you implement a log within `getUser()` to make sure that the funciton is called? Can you deploy your code as a new WebApp version and verify either you still experience discrepancy between the WebApp and sidebar behaviou? How did you deploy your WebApp? Can you return the user object successfully if you replace `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` through `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()`?

Comment: @Rubén - there is no error message.